# Can't get initial value as modelchoicefield in django form

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, choicefield, modelchoicefield

I have a column list. I'm trying to update one row from that list. After i select a row, i am trying to update it. After i select a row, i get one of  the parameters which is table_id. table_id is defined in model.py and forms.py . I show that table_id as modelchoicefield in djangoproject but i can't initiate my instance value as modelchoicefield.

updateView.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,get_object_or_404
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from Columns_definition.forms import ColumnsDefinitionsForms
from Columns_definition.models import sysColumns


 def update_table(request,id):

column_data = get_object_or_404(sysColumns, id = id)
columns_form = ColumnsDefinitionsForms(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance = column_data)



if columns_form.is_valid():
    aciklama = request.POST.get('tabloid')
    columns_form.save()
    messages.info(request, "\'" + column_data.name + "\'" + "{}".format((": is updated")))
    return redirect("Columns_definition:columns_def")


context = {
    "columns_form":columns_form,
    "id":id,
}

return render(request, 'columnsCreate.html', context)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from Columns_definition.models import sysColumns
from Utilities.custom_enum import DataTypes
from Table_definition.models import sysTables


class ColumnsDefinitionsForms(forms.ModelForm):

datatype = forms.ChoiceField(choices=DataTypes, required=False, label='Alan Veri Tipi' , widget=forms.Select(attrs={
      'placeholder': '','class':'form-control select-access-open select2-hidden-accessible popUp'
      }))
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(ColumnsDefinitionsForms, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['datatype'].choices.insert(0, ('','---------' ) )

tabloid = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=sysTables.objects.all(),
 empty_label=None,
widget=forms.Select(attrs={
      'class': 'form-control select-access-open select2-hidden-accessible'
      }))



class Meta:
    model = sysColumns


    fields = [  'tabloid',
                'name',
                'alias' , 
                'aliasLng1' ,
                'aliasLng2' ,
                'visible',
                'datatype',
                'datalength',
                'comboid' ,
                'reftype'  
                ]

    widgets = {

        'name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
        'alias': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
        'aliasLng1': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
        'aliasLng2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
        'visible': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','class':'form-check-input','id':'visible'}),
        'datalength':forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','id':'datalength','class':'form-control  rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
        'comboid': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','id':'comboid','class':'form-control  rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),
        'reftype': forms.NumberInput(attrs={'placeholder': '','id':'reftype','class':'form-control  rc-form-control-input form-control-user'}),

    }
```

models.py

sysColumns

```
  from django.db import models
  import uuid
  from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
  from Table_definition.models import sysTables
  from model_utils import Choices



DataTypes=(
(0 , 'String'),
(1 , 'Numeric'),
(2 ,'Currency' ),
(3 ,'DateTime' ),
(4 ,'Yes/No' ),
(5 ,'UUID' ),
(6 ,'Combo' ),
(7 ,'Image / Binary' ),
 )

class sysColumns(models.Model):

class Meta:
    db_table = 'sysColumns'

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
tableid=models.ForeignKey(sysTables, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(_('Alan Adı'),max_length=64,null=False, blank=False)
alias = models.CharField(_('Alan Açıklaması (Yerel Dil)'),max_length=100,null=False, blank=False)
aliasLng1 = models.CharField(_('Alan Açıklaması (Dil-1)'),max_length=100,null=False, blank=False)
aliasLng2 = models.CharField(_('Alan Açıklaması (Dil-2)'),max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
visible = models.BooleanField(_('Görünüm'),null=True,blank=True)
datatype = models.IntegerField(_('Alanın Veri Tipi'),null=True,blank=True,choices=DataTypes)
datalength = models.IntegerField(_('Alanın Uzunluğu'),null=True,blank=True)
comboid = models.IntegerField(_('Kombo Değeri'),null=True,blank=True)
reftype =models.IntegerField(_('Referans Tipi'),null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

SysTables - Models.py

```
from django.db import models
import uuid
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _



class sysTables(models.Model):

class Meta:
    db_table = 'sysTables'

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True,default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
name = models.CharField(_('Tablo Adı'),max_length=64,null=False, blank=False)
alias = models.CharField(_('Tablo Açıklaması (Yerel Dil)'),max_length=100,null=False, blank=False)
aliasLng1 = models.CharField(_('Tablo Açıklaması (Dil-1)'),max_length=100,null=False, blank=False)
aliasLng2 = models.CharField(_('Tablo Açıklaması (Dil-2)'),max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
chistory = models.BooleanField(_('Yeni Kayıt Tarihçesi '),null=True,blank=True)
rhistory = models.BooleanField(_('Kayıt Okuma Tarihçesi'),null=True,blank=True)
uhistory = models.BooleanField(_('Kayıt Güncelleme Tarihçesi'),null=True,blank=True)
dhistory = models.BooleanField(_('Kayıt Silme Tarihçesi '),null=True,blank=True)
log = models.BooleanField(_('Kayıt Logu'),null=True,blank=True)







def __str__(self):
    return self.alias
```

columnsCreate.html

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-12">
   <div class="card">
     <div class="card-header">
       <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
           <div class="header-elements-inline">
             {% if islem_turu == "detay" %}

          <legend class="text-uppercase font-size-sm font-weight-bold">{% trans " Kolon Detay Kartı " %}</legend>

          {% elif islem_turu == "guncelle"%}

            <legend class="text-uppercase font-size-sm font-weight-bold">{% trans " Kolon Güncelle Kartı " %}</legend>

          {% else %}

            <legend class="text-uppercase font-size-sm font-weight-bold">{% trans " Kolon Oluşturma Kartı " %}</legend>

          {% endif %}

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-body">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1">
        <form method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}

          {% for field in columns_form %}
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label class="col-lg-3 col-form-label"> {{field.label}}
            </label>
            <div class="col-lg-9">
              {{ field }}
            </div>
          </div>

          {% endfor %}





          {% if islem_turu == "detay" %}

          {% elif islem_turu == "guncelle" %}
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" style="margin:.5em; width:8em; float:right; color: #333;background: #41bd1e;" type="submit">
          <i class="icon-floppy-disk " style="color: #333; background:#41bd1e;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{% trans "Kaydet" %}
        </button>

          {% else %}
          <button class="btn btn-info btn-md" style="margin:.5em; width:8em; float:right; color: #333;background: #41bd1e;" type="submit">
          <i class="icon-floppy-disk " style="color: #333; background:#41bd1e;"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;{% trans "Kaydet" %}
        </button>
          <a href="{% url 'Columns_definition:columns_def'  %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-md"
            style="margin:.5em; width:8em; float:right;">
            <i class="fas fa-close"></i>&nbsp; {% trans "İptal" %}
          </a> 
          {% endif %}
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

[combo selection  list (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Szm4L.png)

[combo selection update (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vmhmx.png)

[columns list (3)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idRXn.png)

[columns update (4)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhExg.png)

Edit: When you check (1) and after pressing update button then in picture (2) you can see that i get comboid from (1) in (2) as my selected modelchoicefield. But in (3) my tableid doesn't match up with my tableid in (4). I can't get in (4) what is selected previously on (3). Instead i get my first element of tableid values from database in modelchoicefield.

I expect to select field of table_id in column_data and send it to initial value and want to select it as default modelchoicefield. I made a a lot of examples in my other projects but can't work it out on this one. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you saying that the initial value for the `tableid` field isn't shown based on the existing `columns_data` object that you're updating? This doesn't make sense: "I expect to select field of table_id in column_data and send it to initial value and want to select it as default modelchoicefield."

Comment: @dirkgroten Hi, before i update form , selected initial value doesn't seen as tableid in the modelchoicefield. Instead i get first element from database as my tableid, not the one i'm updating. I want to show the tableid that i selected to update.

Comment: You’re updating a `sysColumns` instance, which has an initial `tableid` value. The value you see initially should be that value. Your code looks correct. I don’t understand “the tableid I selected” you’re not selecting a tableid to update you’re selecting a `sysColumns`.

Comment: @dirkgroten I can't get tableid value from database as  selected in modelchoicefield of update form while updating a row of sysColumns.

Comment: Ok. Maybe show the template code. Also show us some screenshots of what you see that’s wrong. I would also suggest to separate the GET and POST cases in your view (`if request.method == “POST”`), as all the Django tutorials teach you to do. Although that shouldn’t make a difference for this specific issue.

Comment: @dirkgroten i added template and an edit to the post with screenshots.( I can't refer more than 8 links since i'm under 10 rep. had to put numbers myself)

Comment: Can't see what's causing this issue. Try setting a debugger breakpoint in your view, after initialising the `columns_form` and check the value of `columns_form.instance` and `columns_form['tableid'].initial`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think, cause of problem is variable name in forms.py. in Forms.py tabloid should be defined as tableid. Because of your project use modelform library in forms.py. Object in forms and models must match in Django  project.

Best Regards,